# How to handle or what to do if there is an Exception in Dispose() method

Tags: c#, exception, dispose

I have not come across any Question/Solution in Stackoverflow for this question which has got some high number of votes.

So I thought I will ask it again here.

How to handle or what to do if there is an Exception in Dispose() method.

Shall we Log it or if I Rethrow the Exception, will it get Rethrown. I might want to Rethrow it so that I come to know I made a mistake somewhere in my Dispose()

Even If we suppose it does get Rethrown, will it be a good practice to rethrow it?

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), a `Dispose` method should be callable multiple times without throwing an exception. If it throws, it's probably not implemented correctly.

Comment: It is a truth that you can't handle, get rid of try/catch.

Comment: Thanx both of you.

Answer (score 0):

In most (but not all) cases, your exception handlers should be at the code entry point.
Just let the exception bubble up, like this.

```cs
public static class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      using (new QuestionableCodeAtBest()) {}
    } 
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
  }
}

class QuestionableCodeAtBest : IDisposable
{
  const int TotalHands = 2;

  public void Dispose()
  {    
    var handsThatAreClapping = 0;
    Console.WriteLine($"What is the sound of no hands clapping?: {TotalHands / handsThatAreClapping}");
  }
}
```